# ProcessMaker - ProcessMaker\BusinessModel\User

Tags: processmaker

I'm running PM 3.7 and I have a problem as follow.
I'm trying to create new users (in a new installation), but I'm unable to select roles because they simply don't appear in the dropdown menu.
So I tried by devOps and I find that userAjax  answers in this way for this field
*"{"success":false,"error":" [wrapped: Could not execute query [Native Error: Incorrect DATETIME value: ''] [User Info: SELECT RBAC_ROLES.ROL_UID, RBAC_ROLES.ROL_PARENT, RBAC_ROLES.ROL_SYSTEM, RBAC_SYSTEMS.SYS_CODE, RBAC_ROLES.ROL_CODE, RBAC_ROLES.ROL_CREATE_DATE, RBAC_ROLES.ROL_UPDATE_DATE, RBAC_ROLES.ROL_STATUS FROM RBAC_ROLES, RBAC_SYSTEMS WHERE RBAC_ROLES.ROL_UID<>'' AND RBAC_ROLES.ROL_CODE<>'PROCESSMAKER_GUEST' AND RBAC_SYSTEMS.SYS_CODE='PROCESSMAKER' AND RBAC_ROLES.ROL_CREATE_DATE<>'' AND RBAC_ROLES.ROL_UPDATE_DATE<>'' AND RBAC_ROLES.ROL_SYSTEM=RBAC_SYSTEMS.SYS_UID]]"}*"

I've yet verified mySQL doesn't accept *"RBAC_ROLES.ROL_CREATE_DATE<>'' AND RBAC_ROLES.ROL_UPDATE_DATE<>''"*, **it wants "RBAC_ROLES.ROL_CREATE_DATE IS NOT NULL AND RBAC_ROLES.ROL_UPDATE_DATE IS NOT NULL"**, so I'm trying to change the SQL construction in the code. 
I found the BusinessModel\User and the classes UserRoles and BaseUserRoles, but I'm unable to prosecute, to find where I have to modify the code.

 Please, are you able to indicate me where I have to prosecute? Thank you in advance

Comment: Why are you trying to do it via direct db creation? I would recommend using the rest api or PM Functions if this is needed within a trigger. Touching the database, especially for things like this is very risky.

Comment: I'm only trying to understand where is the wrong query in the code. But I suppose the query is built by more parts contributed by different part of the code. The problem seems in different versions of the db, actually I'm running mysql8. Thank you

Comment: yeah there are a lot of places that touch the db. if you are just trying to understand, have fun :) it's a very deep rabbit hole though, talking from experience :-) btw, have you tried pm4?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the native, built in PM Functions if you really need to query the database directly.

You can find them documented here: https://wiki.processmaker.com/3.2/ProcessMaker_Functions/Database_Functions